# What happens to ScriptBundle and StyleBundle in Asp.NET 5.0 vNEXT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, scriptbundle, stylebundle

In vNEXT, what happens to the bundling support via `ScriptBundle` and `StyleBundle`?
**My understanding is that bower, grunt & co. will completely replace that mechanism?**

Are there examples on how to do that?
What I've found is a nice intro by Scott Allen on Pluralsight, but nothing else.

Comment: I thought these were all brought in through a NuGet package anyway and not part of the core of MVC in any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this conversation on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/156) it seems that there will be a choice.

> In general we're moving away from runtime minification and are trying
>   to follow what the current client side ecosystem is trending towards,
>   grunt/gulp/bower etc. When we play in that world we get the benefits
>   of the ecosystem for free without having to rebuild all of the
>   extensibility ourselves.
>
> That said, it is a choice thing and we'll be pushing people down that
>   path, but libraries like SquishIt will always be around and will
>   likely support ASP.NET as well as ASP.NET vnext.
>
> - [David Fowl](https://github.com/davidfowl), Microsoft

So, in summary Microsoft are pushing people in the Grunt (etc.) direction, and it will be the preferred route, but not the only route. It won't "replace [the StyleBundle/ScriptBundle] mechanism" but give you additional choice. However, it does seem (reading between the lines) that StyleBundle/ScriptBundle may not be (as) actively developed any more - as they are Microsoft technologies. But if you want the same kind of functionality then it make make sense to move to a framework like [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt).